# SocketException: Connection failed (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1) with flutter app on macOS

Tags: macos, flutter, http, flutter-http

I have following code in my Flutter app where `MyDataLoader` is a widget which starts up from `main.dart`

**Code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class MyDataLoader extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyDataLoaderState createState() => _MyDataLoaderState();
}

class _MyDataLoaderState extends State<MyDataLoader> {
  void getData() async {
    final response = await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1');
    print(response);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Text('MyDataLoader screen'),
    );
  }
}
```

**Question:**
Above code is inspired from https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data. I get the following error when `MyDataLoader` widget loads up:

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception:
> SocketException: Connection failed (OS Error: Operation not permitted,
> errno = 1), address = jsonplaceholder.typicode.com, port = 443

Above error is of course because of the following line of code called when my widget is loading.

> final response = await
> http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1');

**But**, if I open https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1 on my browser, I am able to to see that it has dummy json which I expect to receive in the response. This means I am well connected to internet.

I am running my app on *macOS Big Sur version 11.1*.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to **declare some permissions** for my app to be able to access internet from a macOS environment?

Comment: Yes. Looks like you're missing something in the macOS app config. https://flutter.dev/desktop#setting-up-entitlements

Comment: Oh yes. I am missing permission @ashu

Comment: Just adding `<key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
 <true/>` to entitlements file solved it. Thanks @ashu

Answer (score 298, accepted):

macOS needs you to request a specific entitlement in order to access the network. To do that open **macos/Runner/DebugProfile.entitlements** and add the following key-value pair.

```
<key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
<true/>
```

Then do the same thing in **macos/Runner/Release.entitlements**.

You need to stop and restart the app for the changes to take effect.

See also [Setting up entitlements](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/macos/building#setting-up-entitlements) in the documentation.