# Google & Microsoft OAuth2 login flow Flutter Desktop (MacOS, Windows, Linux)

Tags: flutter, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, flutter-desktop, flutter-windows

How do you implement Google OAuth2 or Microsoft (Azure) OAuth2 login on Flutter Desktop?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Answering my own question. The overarching process to get the OAuth2 result is:

1. You have to have the desktop app host a local server and have the OAuth services redirect to `http://localhost:#####/` that the dart app is listening to.
2. Launch the URL to start the OAuth2 flow in the browser using [oauth2](https://pub.dev/packages/oauth2_client)
3. On first return to the server, process the OAuth2 response using [oauth2](https://pub.dev/packages/oauth2_client)

**Setup the OAuth flows you want to support.** This is what I used:

1. Go to [google admin](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) or [azure dashboard](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/RegisteredApps),
2. create a new app + add in `Authorized redirect URIs` the localhost url: `http://localhost/`
3. Copy the generated clientId and clientSecret into the configuration below:

```dart
enum LoginProvider { google, azure }

extension LoginProviderExtension on LoginProvider {
  String get key {
    switch (this) {
      case LoginProvider.google:
        return 'google';
      case LoginProvider.azure:
        return 'azure';
    }
  }

  String get authorizationEndpoint {
    switch (this) {
      case LoginProvider.google:
        return "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth";
      case LoginProvider.azure:
        return "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize";
    }
  }

  String get tokenEndpoint {
    switch (this) {
      case LoginProvider.google:
        return "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token";
      case LoginProvider.azure:
        return "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token";
    }
  }

  String get clientId {
    switch (this) {
      case LoginProvider.google:
        return "GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID";
      case LoginProvider.azure:
        return "AZURE_CLIENT_ID";
    }
  }

  String? get clientSecret {
    switch (this) {
      case LoginProvider.google:
        return "GOOGLE_SECRET"; // if applicable
      case LoginProvider.azure:
        return "AZURE_SECRET"; // if applicable
    }
  }

  List<String> get scopes {
    return ['openid', 'email']; // OAuth Scopes
  }
}
```

**Setup the OAuth Manager to create listen for the oauth2 redirect**

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:oauth2/oauth2.dart' as oauth2;
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:window_to_front/window_to_front.dart';

class DesktopLoginManager {
  HttpServer? redirectServer;
  oauth2.Client? client;

  // Launch the URL in the browser using url_launcher
  Future<void> redirect(Uri authorizationUrl) async {
    var url = authorizationUrl.toString();
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Could not launch $url');
    }
  }

  Future<Map<String, String>> listen() async {
    var request = await redirectServer!.first;
    var params = request.uri.queryParameters;
    await WindowToFront.activate(); // Using window_to_front package to bring the window to the front after successful login.  
    request.response.statusCode = 200;
    request.response.headers.set('content-type', 'text/plain');
    request.response.writeln('Authenticated! You can close this tab.');
    await request.response.close();
    await redirectServer!.close();
    redirectServer = null;
    return params;
  }
}
```

```dart
class DesktopOAuthManager extends DesktopLoginManager {
  final LoginProvider loginProvider;

  DesktopOAuthManager({
    required this.loginProvider,
  }) : super();

  void login() async {
    await redirectServer?.close();
    // Bind to an ephemeral port on localhost
    redirectServer = await HttpServer.bind('localhost', 0);
    final redirectURL = 'http://localhost:${redirectServer!.port}/auth';
    var authenticatedHttpClient =
        await _getOAuth2Client(Uri.parse(redirectURL));
    print("CREDENTIALS ${authenticatedHttpClient.credentials}");
    /// HANDLE SUCCESSFULL LOGIN RESPONSE HERE
    return;
  }

  Future<oauth2.Client> _getOAuth2Client(Uri redirectUrl) async {
    var grant = oauth2.AuthorizationCodeGrant(
      loginProvider.clientId,
      Uri.parse(loginProvider.authorizationEndpoint),
      Uri.parse(loginProvider.tokenEndpoint),
      httpClient: _JsonAcceptingHttpClient(),
      secret: loginProvider.clientSecret,
    );
    var authorizationUrl =
        grant.getAuthorizationUrl(redirectUrl, scopes: loginProvider.scopes);

    await redirect(authorizationUrl);
    var responseQueryParameters = await listen();
    var client =
        await grant.handleAuthorizationResponse(responseQueryParameters);
    return client;
  }
}

class _JsonAcceptingHttpClient extends http.BaseClient {
  final _httpClient = http.Client();
  @override
  Future<http.StreamedResponse> send(http.BaseRequest request) {
    request.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
    return _httpClient.send(request);
  }
}
```

Begin the login flow using

GOOGLE:

```dart
if (Platform.isMacOS || Platform.isWindows || Platform.isLinux) {
   final provider = DesktopOAuthManager(loginProvider: LoginProvider.google);
   provider.login();
}
```

AZURE:

```dart
if (Platform.isMacOS || Platform.isWindows || Platform.isLinux) {
   final provider = DesktopOAuthManager(loginProvider: LoginProvider. azure);
   provider.login();
}
```

You're done!

Comment: Ah! Run your own http server to listen for the response! I don't know why I didn't think of that.. Thanks!

Comment: Fantastic! Adding my hurdles to save the next person: On MacOS you need to add an com.apple.security.network.client entitlement as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65458903/socketexception-connection-failed-os-error-operation-not-permitted-errno-1

And if you get a redirect_uri_mismatch, make sure to add http://localhost/auth  to your redirect URI's (no port!). Many more things to try here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch

Comment: That is to say `http://localhost/auth` (couldn't edit my previous comment)

Comment: thanks @OdedBenDov for that addition! I only tested on windows when originally writing this. Glad it still works a year later.

Comment: This was extremely helpful, thank you! I got it working in a macOS app that uses the Dropbox API.

Comment: It seems that Apple support neither localhost nor http (without s).

Comment: Anyone know how to create a firebase instance from the credentials returned? Currently, I do not think this works on windows due to platform support

Answer (score 1):

To add on @Neal's great answer,

If you want his code to return a refresh token as well, add this:

```
var authorizationUrl = 
    grant.getAuthorizationUrl(redirectUrl, scopes: loginProvider.scopes);

// ADD THIS:
authorizationUrl = authorizationUrl.replace(queryParameters: {
    ...authorizationUrl.queryParameters,
    "access_type": "offline",  
});
```