# Flutter Windows Google Authentication Without google_sign_in

Tags: windows, flutter, authentication, google-signin, google-authentication

The google_sign_in package doesn't seem to support Google authentication on Windows. Is there a way to do Google sign-in on Flutter Windows without this package? I'm guessing that we need to open a web view that takes the user to Google sign-in and then somehow retrieves the token after the user has signed in. A sample would be really awesome.

Comment: This answer gets you what you want (although still using google-sign-in): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68716993/google-microsoft-oauth2-login-flow-flutter-desktop-macos-windows-linux

Comment: Hi @christian-findlay, it's 2 years later, got a workaround yet?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [googleapis_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis_auth).

```
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void _lauchAuthInBrowser(String url) async {
  await canLaunch(url) ? await launch(url) : throw 'Could not lauch $url';
}

void _loginWindowsDesktop() {
  var id = ClientId(
    <clientID>,
    <secret>,
  );
  var scopes = [
    'email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
  ];
  
  var client = Client();
  obtainAccessCredentialsViaUserConsent(
     id, scopes, client, (url) => _lauchAuthInBrowser(url))
       .then((AccessCredentials credentials) {
    final driveApi = DriveApi(client);
    client.close();
  });
}
```

Comment: This looks promising. Where are the Client and DriveApi classes from? Which package? Is there a working sample I can look at somewhere? This does not compile for me even with the googleapis_auth installed

Answer (score 0):

There is a note in this plugin - to not be used in flutter app, as it could be decompiled and the secret exposed. Others have had similar requirements and have done a workaround https://bselwesiuk.medium.com/social-authentication-in-flutter-desktop-apps-c8c0599e13d3 . Will test it myself soon.