# How to do Oauth 1.0 in flutter desktop

Tags: python, flutter, dart, oauth, netsuite

Im trying to connect to Netsuite using flutter and struggling to understand how I can do oauth. In python I do this:

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session
import os

oauth = OAuth1Session(
    client_key=os.environ['NETSUITE_CLIENT_KEY'],
    client_secret=os.environ['NETSUITE_CLIENT_SECRET'],
    resource_owner_key=os.environ['NETSUITE_TOKEN_KEY'],
    resource_owner_secret=os.environ['NETSUITE_TOKEN_SECRET'],
    realm='123456')

 r = oauth.get(
        url,
        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        params=params
    )
```

How do I do something like this in dart? I was guessing the `oauth2` library is the answer but I have no clue how to get it to work. How do I go about this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google & Microsoft OAuth2 login flow Flutter Desktop (MacOS, Windows, Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68716993/google-microsoft-oauth2-login-flow-flutter-desktop-macos-windows-linux)

Comment: Hi unfortunately no. The solution involves opening a browser, starting a server etc which is not what the python library does as it uses api keys so no need for a browser.