# Flutter/dart - Connection failed

Tags: flutter, dart, http

I created the simplest GET (spring boot backend) imaginable:
[...]

```
@GetMapping("basic")
@ResponseBody
public void basic2() {
    System.out.println("basic get invoked");
}
```

[...]
I'm trying to create a flutter mobile app client for this.
I can invoke it via curl and I try to invoke it like this:

```
Future<void> _fetchData(String email) async {
   http.Response response = await 
   http.get(Uri.parse("http://localhost:8080/basic"));
   print(response.statusCode);
}
```

Internet access is enabled in android manifest.
I always get the same issue.
'Unhandled Exception: Connection failed'

Do you have any idea why am I getting this?

Tried with/without port. With/with http protocol. I see in the documentation this is the way, but it doesn't want to work really.

Comment: Are you sure the *localhost* is the same of the backend?

Comment: unless your device or simulator does some kind of proxy magic from the devices/simulators localhost to your host computer, this will not work. first of all, spring must listen on all IPs, not only localhost. then you need to find the IP of you host that faces your device. e.g. in the same wifi thats your wifi IP

Comment: I'm testing locally, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your Spring backend runs on your host operating system, not on the Android emulated device itself. You need to use `10.0.2.2` as your "new" `localhost`.

[How can I access my localhost from my Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device)

This doesn't apply on the iOS simulator though.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. So I added a try-catch block and looked into the exception and I saw it's a

> SocketException: Connection failed (OS Error: Operation not permitted,
> errno = 1)

and I figured I'm missing the permission in DebugProfile.entitlements. I added

> com.apple.security.network.client
>
> and it works!

Also this article is about my issue: [SocketException: Connection failed (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1) with flutter app on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65458903/socketexception-connection-failed-os-error-operation-not-permitted-errno-1)

Thank you guys for the help!